# rspec using old files when rerunning tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rails-spring

This is my first project in Rails 4, I'm using 4.2

I'm finding that rspec is not reloading my spec files each time it runs, so tests that I've fixed continue to fail with the old error message.

I'm guessing this has something to do with spring but I can't seem to find information on how to configure paths it should reload.

I'm launching rspec using `bin/rspec`, and here's my Gemfile if that's of use.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Angular CSRF handling
gem 'angular_rails_csrf'

gem 'pg'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sass', '3.2.19'
group :test, :development do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "teaspoon-jasmine"
  gem 'teaspoon'
  gem 'phantomjs'
  gem 'guard-teaspoon'
  gem 'spring-commands-teaspoon'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-readline'
  gem 'rb-fsevent' if `uname` =~ /Darwin/
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.8.6'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '1.3.6'
end

# Preload angular templates
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Apparently I had two files which had near identical names. So while I updated one, rspec was testing the other. so it seemed like rspec was testing an old spec file (which I thought had been updated). i deleted one of the files and it all worked as normal. Hope this helps someone.